# Cannot delete ubuntu directory from EFI partition

Tags: ubuntu, efi, dualboot

I followed this answer trying to delete Ubuntu from dualboot https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150814/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-efi-partition

Error states that there's no such directory, even though it just showed that there is.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODKgf.png

Edit: Solved by typing `rmdir F:\EFI\ubuntu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by typing `rmdir F:\EFI\ubuntu`, instead of `rmdir /S ubuntu`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).